# can click one button at the time jquery

Tags: jquery

let's say I have two buttons, and when I click on button1 for example I want the button2 to be disabled, and same thing for clicking a button2 being button1 disabled. I want one button to be clickable at the time.How can I do this ? thanks in advance.

```
<div class="container">

<button type="button" id="button1" class="buttons">button1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2" class="buttons">button2</button>

</div>


$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "buttons" ).click(function() {

  });
});
```

I was thinking about using `.attr('disabled', true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : You need to put `.`(dot) before classname while using class selector in jQuery. You can make use of `siblings()` to get all buttons at same level and the use `prop('disabled',true)` for making buttons disabled.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".buttons" ).click(function() {
     $(this).siblings('.buttons').prop('disabled',true);
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mjx2f2np/)**

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="container">

<button type="button" id="button1" disabled class="buttons">button1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2" class="buttons">button2</button>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#button1" ).click(function() {
    $("#button2").removeAttr('disabled');  
    $("#button1").attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
   $( "#button2" ).click(function() {
    $("#button1").removeAttr('disabled');  
    $("#button2").attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
});

</script>
```